# Erlang Iterating through list removing one element

Tags: list, functional-programming, erlang, runtime

I have the following erlang code:

```
lists:all(fun(Element) -> somefunction(TestCase -- [Element]) end, TestCase).
```

Where TestCase is an array.  I'm trying to iterate over the list/array with one element missing.

The problem is this code takes O(N^2) time worst case because of the copies of the TestCase array everytime `--` is called.  There is a clear O(N) Solution in a non functional language.

```
saved = TestCase[0]
temp = 0
NewTestCase = TestCase[1:] 
for a in range(length(NewTestCase)):
  somefunction(NewTestCase)
  temp = NewTestCase[a]
  NewTestCase[a] = saved
  saved = temp
```

... or something like that.

Is there an O(N) solution in erlang?

Comment: A linked list is not efficient for this kind of manipulation. Use the `sets` data structure instead and you will see your efficiency soar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is, but it's a little bit more complicated. I am assuming that `some_function/1` is indeed a boolean function and you want to test whether it returns true for every sub-list.

```
test_on_all_but_one([], _Acc) -> true;
test_on_all_but_one([E|Rest], Acc) ->
  case somefunction(lists:reverse(Acc,Rest)) of
    true  -> test_on_all_but_one(Rest, [E|Acc]);
    false -> false
  end.
```

This implementation is still O(length(List)^2) as the `lists:reverse/2` call will still need O(`length(Acc)`). If you can modify `somefunction/1` to do it's calculation on a list split into two parts, then you can modify the previous call to `somefunction(lists:reverse(Acc,Rest))` with `somefunction(Acc, Rest)` or something similar and avoid the reconstruction.

The modification depends on the inner workings of `somefunction/1`. If you want more help with that, give some code!

Answer (score 0):

You can split the list into 2 sublists, if it's acceptable of course.

```
witerate(Fun, [Tail], Acc) ->
  Fun([], Acc);

witerate(Fun, [Head | Tail], Acc) ->
  Fun(Tail, Acc),
  witerate(Fun, Tail, [Head | Acc]).
```